How do I install a 3rd-party package with pip, system-wide?
I have just installed Xubuntu 24.04.1 and have had my share of problems. One of them relates to the installation of 3rd-party packages such as fipy, CoolProp, etc. In 22.04, I would typically execute:
sudo python3 -m pip install fipy

and then fipy (or any other package) would go to the proper place. Now I don't seem to be able to do that any more. If I execute a command such as the one above I will get:
sudo python3 -m pip install python3-numpy
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

How can I bypass this? I know virtual environments are safe(r), but I prefer the old way. Also, I am not acquainted to virtual environments and don't want to use my time to learn about their creation and usage.
Thanks.

@muru It's indeed a similar question as I verified later. Thanks.

What about installing python3-numpy using the apt package?
apt info python3-numpy
Package: python3-numpy
Version: 1:1.26.4+ds-6ubuntu1
Priority: optional
Section: python
Source: numpy
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com
Original-Maintainer: Debian Python Team team+python@tracker.debian.org,
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 23.9 MB
...

@xpk My example using python3-numpy was not a good one. It misleads people into thinking that I was trying to install numpy via pip, what is not wise. Sorry.
